# Align the search and menu bar on headermenu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why it can not align correctly. I have tried: display, align changing the margins, changing the padding, changing the position. event the top or doing a float on it.

[Photo of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoE6r.png)

```css
.headerMenu {
  background-color: #272626;
  Height: 56px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.logo {
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  width: 38px;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.logo .img {
  background-image: url(../img/logo-white-p.png);
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.logo:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}
.logo .img:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/logo-black-p.png);
}
.search_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  margin-left: 155px;
}
#search input[type="text"] {
  background: url(../img/search-icon-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #000;
  outline: none;
  border: 0 none;
  font: bold 12px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fff;
  color: #6a6f75;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
  -box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu {
    postion: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right0px;
    height: 37px;
    padding-top: 19px;
  }
}
#menu a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerMenu">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="serch_box">
      <form action="serch.php" method="get" id="search">
        <input type="text" name="q" size="60px" placeholder="Search..." />
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected result you want ?

Comment: I want the result of the search bar and the menu tag to appear on the header menu not just floating down

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the fact that a `div` element is a block element and therefore forces itself to a new line.

If we tell the system to make each `div` under the `#wrapper` to be an inline element, then it will all line up as expected.

It also requires `vertical-align: middle` to make everything align to the middle of the header. If this isn't present then it sets it to the bottom of the header element.

```css
.headerMenu {
  background-color: #272626;
  Height: 56px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
div#wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo {
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  width: 38px;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.logo .img {
  background-image: url(../img/logo-white-p.png);
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.logo:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}
.logo .img:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/logo-black-p.png);
}
.search_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  margin-left: 155px;
}
#search input[type="text"] {
  background: url(../img/search-icon-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #000;
  outline: none;
  border: 0 none;
  font: bold 12px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fff;
  color: #6a6f75;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
  -box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu {
    postion: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right0px;
    height: 37px;
    padding-top: 19px;
  }
}
#menu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerMenu">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="serch_box">
      <form action="serch.php" method="get" id="search">
        <input type="text" name="q" size="60px" placeholder="Search..." />
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TheLiveitup34 an accepted answer (the tick under the upvote/downvote area) would be amazing and useful for future users :). Cheers and no problem :)